# Trocar variaveis dos documentos word selecionados

Tags: c#

vi bastante exemplos de troca de variáveis em documento word com find replace, porem apenas com um documento, sendo passado o caminho do mesmo em um 'object template(permite apenas um documento informado)'.No meu caso eu trago vários documentos word de um diretório(em um checklistbox) e gostaria de trocar variável dos que estarão selecionados(mais de um).Como faço?

Faz a troca das variaveis:

```
               //Objeto a ser usado nos parâmetros opcionais
                object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
                //Abre a aplicação Word e faz uma cópia do documento mapeado
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application oApp = new 
                Word.Application();
                object template = @"C:\Teste\ABASTECEDOR DE GLP.docx";
                Word.Document oDoc = oApp.Documents.Add(ref template, ref 
                missing, ref missing, ref missing);
                //Troca o conteúdo de alguns tags
                Word.Range oRng = oDoc.Range(ref missing, ref missing);
```

---

```
                object FindText = "@var1";
                object ReplaceWith = c.codigo;
                object MatchWholeWord = true;
                object Forward = false;
                oRng.Find.Execute(ref FindText, ref missing, ref MatchWholeWord, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref Forward,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref ReplaceWith, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
                oRng = oDoc.Range(ref missing, ref missing);


                FindText = "@var2";
                ReplaceWith = c.nome;
                oRng.Find.Execute(ref FindText, ref missing, ref MatchWholeWord, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref Forward,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref ReplaceWith, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
                oRng = oDoc.Range(ref missing, ref missing);


                FindText = "@var3";
                ReplaceWith = c.setor;
                oRng.Find.Execute(ref FindText, ref missing, ref MatchWholeWord, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref Forward,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref ReplaceWith, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
                oRng = oDoc.Range(ref missing, ref missing);
```

Comment: faz o loop trocando as variáveis de um por um. Coloca o código que você tem por favor

Comment: codigo aonde posso passar apenas 1 arquivo. pode me dar um exemplo? @RovannLinhalis os outros que voce passou na outra pergunta eu nao consegui  entender.

Comment: esse código que colocou, está fazendo a troca das variáveis de 1 arquivo ? o modelo, com as variáveis, é o template, certo ? quais dados tem no checkedlistbox ?

Comment: isso, ele esta trocando apenas do arquivo passado no object template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

com o pequeno trecho que colocou, e considerando que o item do checkedlistbox seja o nome do arquivo que você quer alterar, faça uma iteração entre os itens checados:

```
        foreach (string arquivo in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
        {

            FileInfo file = new FileInfo("C:\\Teste\\"+ arquivo);

            if (file.Exists)
            {

            //Objeto a ser usado nos parâmetros opcionais
            object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            //Abre a aplicação Word e faz uma cópia do documento mapeado
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application oApp = new
            Word.Application();
            object template = file.FullName;
            Word.Document oDoc = oApp.Documents.Add(ref template, ref 
            missing, ref missing, ref missing);
            //Troca o conteúdo de alguns tags
            Word.Range oRng = oDoc.Range(ref missing, ref missing);


            object FindText = "@var1";
            object ReplaceWith = c.codigo;
            object MatchWholeWord = true;
            object Forward = false;
            oRng.Find.Execute(ref FindText, ref missing, ref MatchWholeWord, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref Forward,
            ref missing, ref missing, ref ReplaceWith, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
            oRng = oDoc.Range(ref missing, ref missing);


            FindText = "@var2";
            ReplaceWith = c.nome;
            oRng.Find.Execute(ref FindText, ref missing, ref MatchWholeWord, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref Forward,
            ref missing, ref missing, ref ReplaceWith, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
            oRng = oDoc.Range(ref missing, ref missing);


            FindText = "@var3";
            ReplaceWith = c.setor;
            oRng.Find.Execute(ref FindText, ref missing, ref MatchWholeWord, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref Forward,
            ref missing, ref missing, ref ReplaceWith, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
            oRng = oDoc.Range(ref missing, ref missing);



          //Processa o arquivo alterado, Salvar, imprimir, etc..

            }
            else
            {
                  MessageBox.Show("Arquivo " + arquivo + " não existe");

            }

        }
```

Comment: eu faço já essa iteração checando os documentos marcados, porem aonde eu passo o diretório de todos meus documentos pra que ele considere somente os marcados ? algo como isso:

Comment: DirectoryInfo diretorio = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Teste");
            //Executa função GetFile(Lista os arquivos desejados de acordo com o parametro)
            FileInfo[] Arquivos = diretorio.GetFiles("*.docx*");

Comment: por isso que é importante colocar seu código para que possamos ver o que está fazendo. Alterei a resposta

Comment: obrigado @Rovann linhalis

Comment: nao tinha visto sua resposta por completo, funcionou muito obrigado @Rovann Linhalis